# How to find a particular position in a csv file

Tags: csv, import, google-bigquery

I need to upload my csv data into Google big query. However, while uploading it from csv , I'm getting below error:

```
    Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 13, 
    but line starting at position:40244667 contains only 7 columns.
```

Now, problem is that ,I'm unable to identify what it means by position:40244667. How can I reach to/find out this position in my CSV file in order to troubleshoot the error further.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next csv module to read all the data in your csv

```
for line in myfile:  
    row = csv.reader([line]).next()
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use your solution

Comment: Yo can parse the CSV data row by row yourself using the csv module i mentioned above